# How can I correct the screen going blank whenever I run nettop?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm running the latest version of macOS and always just use Terminal. Not iTerm or anything like that.

Whenever I run nettop, the screen goes blank. Sometimes it happens immediately, and sometimes after I press an arrow key.

How do I keep this from happening?

I just tried `r` to redraw the screen, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make your terminal screen bigger. It fixed mine!

Comment: I solved this problem quite some time ago with Apple's support team. I'm so sorry I never gave the answer here!

Answer (score 1):

I sent a bug report about this to Apple. Someone there knew that nettop had been given more columns too display, so he suggested I widen the window. I did this, and found that nettop worked correctly from then on.

I suggested that the default dimensions of the Terminal window be changed to 90*27.